# conditional aggregation in google data studio

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregation, looker-studio

How can I make a conditional aggregation field using Google data studio's calculated fields?

[image]

In the example above - I want to calculate the median only for users with at least one account (accounts > 0)

Comment: How will you be using this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options I can think of.

ONE: You can use CASE statements in your field. But first, you will need to create a **new field** to only include accounts > 0. Anything that doesn't meet the criteria becomes "null".

New_field:

```
CASE
   WHEN accounts > 0 THEN accounts
END
```

Then create another field that takes the MEDIAN of the new_field:

```
MEDIAN(new_field)
```

TWO: Another option if it's for a visualization, you can create your normal field

```
MEDIAN(accounts)
```

but then you will need add a filter (in the data option tab) in your visualization with the condition:

```
INCLUDE  Field="accounts" condition= "Greater Than"  Value="0"
```

Comment: Thanks! in option one - will the median simply not be calculated when the value is null? it won't throw an error?

Comment: I have not it throw any errors when there are nulls in the fields it's aggregating. Aggregation functions generally ignore null values.